# Will a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ be a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$?

Tags: metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Assume we have a function $f: A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ which is uniformly continuous. Will a Cauchy sequence in $A$ be mapped on a Cauchy sequence in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$?

I think this is true if $m < n$, but don't know how to prove it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}^k$, Cauchy and convergent are equivalent. Uniform continuity implies continuity. The trip can be: Start with a Cauchy sequence, then it is convergent, the function being continuous sends convergent sequences to convergent sequences, the image being convergent it Cauchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In general:**

Let $X$ and $Y$ two normed spaces with norm $||\cdot||_A$ and $||\cdot||_B$ respectively. Let $f:A\rightarrow B$ is uniformly continuous. Now take $\{x_n\}$ a Cauchy sequence in $A$ and let $\epsilon>0$. So, exists $\delta>0$ such that
$$
||x-y||_A<\delta\Rightarrow||f(x)-f(y)||_B<\epsilon
$$
Now, take $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$
n,m\geq N\Rightarrow||x_n-x_m||_A<\delta
$$
So
$$
m,n\geq N\Rightarrow||f(x_n)-f(x_m)||_B<\epsilon
$$
This means that $\{f(x_n)\}$ is Cauchy in $B$.

Comment: Thanks, so it doesn't mind that the dimensions of the Euclidean spaces changes for instance from n=2 to m=3?

Comment: No it doesn't matter. This result holds in general metric spaces $A$ and $B$.